# How to render fields with many-to-many relationship on django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, many-to-many

I am using generic views in Django-3.2 where I have a many-to-many relationship. I am trying to put the names of all the authors for a book as a string on a template. The model is like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

The `Author` class has a field called `author_name` which is also returned from the `__str__` method. The generic view class that I am using is like this:

```
class BookView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/book.html'
```

I tried using `<span>{{ book.author }}</span>` which produced `books.Author.None`. Later, I tried using `<span>{{ book.author.author_name }}</span>`, and this didn't retrieve any result. I didn't get an error in either of the cases. How do I put the data on the template for such many-to-many field?

Answer (score 0):

First loop over all your books and display the book name and then for each book loop over all the authors of that book and display their name.

```
{% for book in books %}
   <span>{{ book.book_name }}</span>
   {% for author in book.author.all %}
       <span>{{ author.author_name }}</span>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```